# Getting errors while installing strong loop on my windows 7 environment

Tags: python, node.js, npm, strongloop

I am trying to get StrongLoop working on my Windows 7 machine.

I installed it with npm install -g strongloop

It threw some python errors, which seems to be expected and then execution finished.

I did the npm install npm step as indicated here: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Installing+StrongLoop#InstallingStrongLoop-Windows

When I try 'slc' on the command line it gives the above error. I added it to the path manually and still nothing. Even when I go right into the directory where the slc file is ({user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\bin) and try to use it from there it says the same thing. Like the file that was installed is not executable.

please suggest on this.

Thanks in Advance,
SP

Comment: Did you try reinstalling npm? `npm install -g npm`?

Comment: Your description says "gives the above error" but there is no error message given above at the time I'm typing this. What is the error message?